# See who upvoted a post?

Tags: support, up-votes

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask, but as a new member (or just user? I guess I'm just a user) I don't know any better ...

Question:  Is it possible to see somewhere who upvoted a post or is it -- for understandable reasons -- not?

Comment: Related on the main Meta site: [Is there a way to see who voted on your posts?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/12984)

Comment: Thank you!  I was looking for this information, but didn't find it (apparently the wrong meta).  So it is some form of "democratic voting by secret ballot"!

Comment: You can't call it "democratic" as there is no "result" from the votes that then is acted on when the voting is over. The only thing that the votes result in, over time (since the voting never stops, unless the question is closed, which is not a democratic decision) is a reputation gain/loss for the author and a score on the post. It is simply voting that is anonymous.

Comment: @Kusalananda, you are perfectly right and I even deliberated before posting if I should use the attribute "democratic".  In any case, you seem to have a higher standard concerning the notion "democratic" than me.  I don't want to get political, but I already participated in not just one referendum which was politically ignored.  Any, yes, decisions without consulting the people also happen all the time  --  it is still a democratic system and society!